# Conflict between macro argument #1 and internal #1 argument of the package parselines

Tags: macros, arguments

I want to run this code in order to print all lines (including each of the blank lines) of the argument inside `\PrintAllLines{}`. For that, I would like to use the `parselines` package, because it recognizes well all blank lines. `\obeylines` is not an option, because it doesn't recognize multiple blank lines under each other.

The problem with this code is, that the argument `#1` inside `\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{#1\\}` should be actually what is inserted between `\begin{parse lines}` and `\end{parse lines}` and not the argument `#1`, that was passed by `\PrintAllLines{}`. There's a conflict with both `#1` arguments and I don't know to solve this situation.

Does someone have a good idea how to handle this?

Is it maybe possible to pass an argument through `\PrintAllLines{}`, but using something else then the code `#1`, so that the internal `#1` of `\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{#1\\}` works well?

A MWE would be great, as I'm new to LaTeX and still learning.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parselines}

\renewcommand{\PrintAllLines[1]{
\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{#1\\}
#1
\end{parse lines}
}}

\begin{document}
\PrintAllLines{

line 1

line 2 with multiple spaces above

line 3 with multiple spaces above

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `parse lines` collects the contents of the environment verbatim (that's how it manages to detect line ends), so you cannot grab the environment as the argument to a macro. What you want here is `\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{##1\\}` (with two `#`), but again, grabbing the environment as `#1` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `parselines` was only a means to an end (retaining each linefeed), here is another means.  Using `listofitems`, with a macro definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\PrintAllLines{\begingroup\obeylines\PrintAllLinesAux}
\begingroup
\obeylines
\gdef\PrintAllLinesAux#1{%
  \setsepchar{
  }%
  \readlist\mytest{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mytest[]{\noindent\z\\}%
  \endgroup%
}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
\PrintAllLines{this
is


a

test}

For comparison, normal endline intake:

this
is


a

test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Customization is easy, just by changing the `\foreachitem` argument.  For example, if `\foreachitem\z\in\mytest[]{\noindent\makebox[2em][l]{\scriptsize\zcnt:}\z\\}%` is used, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

As write [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) you can't use `parse lines` environment in `\newcommand` because of implementation features.

But you can define own environment for simplify your work, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parselines}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{my parse lines}
    {\begin{parse lines}[\noindent]{##1\\}}
    {\end{parse lines}}

\begin{my parse lines}

line 1


line 2 with multiple spaces above


line 3 with multiple spaces above
\end{my parse lines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is great and useful too! I accepted the code from @steven just because I was searching for a way to type only `\PrintAllLines{content here}`.